# Robots Meta Tag and query strings

Tags: url, query-string, meta-robots

I am trying to find out something about this tag:

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

If I have a dynamic page like these

1. `example.com/product.aspx?ProductID=123`
2. `example.com/product.aspx?ProductID=456`

If I dynamically add that meta tag for URL #1, will it affect crawling of URL #2?

Technically they are the same page, `product.aspx`. But the content is rendered dynamically based on the `ProductID`.

Answer (score 2):

If you "dynamically add that meta tag" for only the first URL then it will not affect *indexing* of the second.

Whilst it might be the same file (`product.aspx`) that processes both requests, they are two different URLs.

Answer (score 0):

If by "dynamically add that meta tag" you mean that the page only adds the meta tag when it detects the parameter `ProductID=123` and does not add it when it detects the parameter `ProductID=456`, then it will not affect *indexing* and *following links* in URL #2.

Allowing/Disallowing *Crawling* is done by adding the URL to your `robots.txt` file, not by the robots meta tag.

The best way to verify is to check the rendered source code of both URLs. If you DO see the meta tag for both pages, then it will definitely affect URL #2.